# What does "fd" stand for in the context of public key infrastructure?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, rsa, terminology

I'm reading the [OpenSSL Cookbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/openssl-cookbook/). Early in Chapter 1 on page 9, the author generates a private key using the RSA algorithm:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out fd.key 2048
```

I understand that the key could be named anything, for example `foo.key`. I also understand the extension could be anything.

In the case of the extension, it makes sense to use `.key` because it's one of the accepted [Privacy-enhanced Electronic Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) format extensions. Others could be common [accepted PEM extensions] are `.pem`, `.crt`, and `.cer`.

- Why does the author choose `fd`? Is it short for something?

Comment: Perhaps **f**eisty **d**uck, the publisher of the book?

Comment: file descriptor?

Comment: floppy disk. Taking it out of the computer on floppy to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CodesInChaos stated;

If you read the complete chapter, you see that the author is setting up a cert for Feisty Duck Ltd, CN=www.feistyduck.com, it's just the name for that.

As you said also, I understand that the key could be named anything; so the "fd" stands for nothing here, in terms of context in PKI.